# Parallel-Processing in Integrated GPU

Tags: integrated-graphics, parallel-processing

I have an integrated GPU, meaning it works on the same RAM as my CPU. (ATI Radeon HD 4200, integrated on M4A785TD-V EVO)

Does this also mean my GPU doesn't compute in parallel?

see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15436019/parallel-processing-in-integrated-gpu

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modern integrated GPUs work the same way as those dedicated cards with the exception that they share memory with the CPU. They are typically less powerful than the ones on dedicated cards but functionally they work the same. Internally they are massively parallel processing units. The drivers and GPUs break up the task of 3D rendering into multiple calculations that can be done at the same time.

Comment: Does this mean that when I am currently not using the GPU that much I have more CPU available?

Comment: More CPU is probably not the correct term. When the GPU is not being used heavily (like rendering games or movies) there will be less congestion for other resources. In those cases the CPU will be able to operate closer to its full potential.